# Add single element to a sequence for an expression

Tags: c#, linq, sequence

Imagine you would want to select all elements of one sequence `all`, except elements contained in sequence `exceptions` and single element `otherException`.

Is there some better way to do this than? I'd like to avoid creating new array, but I couldn't find a method on the sequence that concats it with a single element.

```
all.Except(exceptions.Concat(new int[] { otherException }));
```

complete source code for completeness' sake:

```
var all = Enumerable.Range(1, 5);
int[] exceptions = { 1, 3 };
int otherException = 2;
var result = all.Except(exceptions.Concat(new int[] { otherException }));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative (perhaps more readable) would be:

```
all.Except(exceptions).Except(new int[] { otherException });
```

You can also create an extension method that converts any object to an IEnumerable, thus making the code even more readable:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this T item)
{
    return new T[] { item };
}

all.Except(exceptions).Except(otherException.ToEnumerable());
```

Or if you really want a reusable way to easily get a collection plus one item:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Plus<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, T item)
{
    return collection.Concat(new T[] { item });
}

all.Except(exceptions.Plus(otherException))
```